# Pytorch's spectral normalization doesn't work with convolutional layers

Tags: python, pytorch

In the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.parametrizations.spectral_norm.html) there is a little example of applying spectral norm to a linear layer and it has the norm being equal to one.

However when I apply it to a conv layer it doesn't make the output equal to one. For example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
snm = nn.utils.spectral_norm(nn.Conv2d(20, 40, 3))

print(torch.linalg.matrix_norm(snm.weight, 2))
```

Is there something wrong with the way I implement it or am I measuring it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone seeing this down the line, I encountered this as well and was also confused. You need to unroll the weights along the layer dimension and it seems correct:

```
from torch.nn.utils.parametrizations import spectral_norm
import torch.nn as nn
m = nn.Conv2d(16, 33, 3, stride=2)
torch.linalg.matrix_norm(spectral_norm(m).weight,2).max()
>>> tensor(0.2038, grad_fn=<MaxBackward1>)
torch.linalg.matrix_norm(spectral_norm(m).weight.reshape(16,-1),2).max()
>>> tensor(1.1341, grad_fn=<MaxBackward1>)
```